# Regular dll to windows phone 8 dll

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a DLL without source code and i want to convert it to windows phone DLL. I am stuck with its conversion, can any body help me? I have googled and found many links but none was useful. I tried to unblock the dll as well but that step also was not useful.

Comment: I have decompiled the whole dll library and used that code to create new one. Thanx for Commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. The regular DLL uses the full .NET Framework. But the Windows Phone will require the ".NET for Windows Phone 8". The only way to convert between them is to get the source code and compile it.

NOTE: you cannot just take any app or DLL and try to put it on the phone. The underlying hardware, OS and platform are very different between normal computers and phones. Even if a functionality you want to perform is simple -- like find the length of a given string -- the underlying code that will run at the hardware level is very very very... different.

Comment: Yes But it must have some method... Any Compiler to make it portable

Answer (score 0):

If it is .NET Dll you can try to decompile it. And than try to compile it for windows phone

Comment: Basically i trying to build ffmeg for my assignement based on windows phone 8 but i am stuck. any suggestions

Comment: You need ARM version of this library. May be [this](http://ffmpegwinrtarm.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-May/000833.html) will help.